# Scheme Helper Function and always returning zero

Tags: hash, functional-programming, scheme, helper

I am trying to write a Scheme function that takes in a list of letters, hashes them with another function, multiplies each one iteratively by 5^i, and sums them together. I am new to Scheme and this is what I have written:

```
(define (key w)
    keyhelper w 0)

(define (keyhelper w i) 
    (cond ((null? w) '())
          (else (+  (* (hashchar(car w) (expt 5 i)) (keyhelper(cdr w) (+ i 1)))))))
```

So for example, doing (key '(h e l l o)) should do hashchar(h)*5^0 + hashchar(e)*5^1 + hashchar(l)^5^2 ... etc. The function is only returning 0 for any list that is sent in. Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

My implementation of hashchar is:

```
(define hashchar
  (lambda (x)
(cond
  ((eq? x 'a) 1)
  ((eq? x 'b) 2)
  ((eq? x 'c) 3)
  ((eq? x 'd) 4)
  ((eq? x 'e) 5)
  ((eq? x 'f) 6)
  ((eq? x 'g) 7)
  ((eq? x 'h) 8)
  ((eq? x 'i) 9)
  ((eq? x 'j) 10)
  ((eq? x 'k) 11)
  ((eq? x 'l) 12)
  ((eq? x 'm) 13)
  ((eq? x 'n) 14)
  ((eq? x 'o) 15)
  ((eq? x 'p) 16)
  ((eq? x 'q) 17)
  ((eq? x 'r) 18)
  ((eq? x 's) 19)
  ((eq? x 't) 20)
  ((eq? x 'u) 21)
  ((eq? x 'v) 22)
  ((eq? x 'w) 23)
  ((eq? x 'x) 24)
  ((eq? x 'y) 25)
  ((eq? x 'z) 26))))
```

Comment: Where is `hashchar` defined?

Comment: hashchar is defined in another file I have included in the beginning. hashchar converts a letter into its number, such as a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, etc.

Comment: Missing opening parenthesis before the call to `keyhelper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` returns zero all the time because you defined it that way. You had:

```
(define (key w)
  keyhelper
  w
  0)
```

thus, it evaluates `keyhelper` (discarding its value), then `w` (discarding its value), then `0` (returning its value). So the answer is always 0.

You should instead define it this way:

```
(define (key w)
  (keyhelper w 0))
```

Notice the extra parentheses.

Also, the base-case value for `keyhelper` is wrong. It shouldn't be `'()`, it should be `i`.

Comment: Thank you, but when I tried that code you posted I get the error: application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments

Answer (score 0):

If your definition of `hashchar` is similar to [this one](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/guile/src/slib/hash.scm):

```
(define (hash:hash-char-ci char n)
  (modulo (char->integer (char-downcase char)) n))

(define hash:hash-char hash:hash-char-ci)
```

Then `hashchar` will return 0 when `i = 0` is passed to `(expt 5 i)` because `(expt 5 i)` is one, and the one-modulo of any integer is zero.

Once you multiply zero into your hash function, then you'll always get zero out...since `+` isn't doing anything but returning identity because it is only passed one argument:

```
(* (hashchar(car w) (expt 5 i)) (keyhelper(cdr w) (+ i 1)))
```

Maybe [`string-hash`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-13.html?q=hashc#string-hash) is a better choice of library function?

Comment: I posted implementation of hashchar above.